# How do I toggle FullScreen with a button in a TMS WEB Core Website?

Tags: delphi, fullscreen, tms, html5-fullscreen, tms-web-core

I'm making a TMS WEB Core website in Delphi where I want to have a button that toggles the website in and out of FullScreen (Like when you press F11 in a browser).

In FireMonkey, you have a `FullScreen` property on the form to do that and then in code in an FMX app, I can literally just do the following code for that:

```
MyForm.FullScreen := not(MyForm.FullScreen)
```

The `TWebForm` doesn't have a `FullScreen` property.

But how can I do this on a website in a browser using Delphi and TMS WEB Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little Delphi function that can toggle `FullScreen` in TMS WEB Core Websites:

```
procedure ToggleFullScreen();
begin
  asm
    if (document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    }
  end;
end;
```

This should work on all modern browsers also. I tested it on Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, and Mozilla Firefox. You can use it by simply calling `ToggleFullScreen()` in a button's `onClick` event:

```
procedure TForm2.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ToggleFullScreen();
end;
```

Comment: `cancelFullScreen()` is an outdated approach over `exitFullScreen()` (if you want to limit it to _modern_ browsers anyway) and [a request may fail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API/Guide).